# jQuery - Save to SQL via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, sql-update

This is probably easy for you guys, but I can't understand it.
I want to save the filename of an image to it's own row in the SQL base.

Basically, I log on to the site where I have my own userID. 
And each user has its own column for background images. And the user can choose his own image if he wants to. So basically, when the user clicks on the image he wants, a jquery click event occurs and an ajax call is made to a php file which is supposed to take care of the actual update. The row for each user always exist so there's only an update of the data that's necessary.

First, I collect the filename of the css property 'background-image' and split it so I get only the filename. I then store that filename in a variable I call 'filename' which is then passed on to this jQuery snippet:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save_to_db.php',
        data: filename,
        dataType:'Text',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // Just for testing purposes.
            alert('Background changed to: ' + data);
   }   

  });
```

And this is the php that saves the data:

```
<?php 
require("dbconnect.php");

$uploadstring = $_POST['filename'];

mysql_query("UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = '$uploadstring' WHERE brukerID=" .$_SESSION['id']);
mysql_close();  
?>
```

Basically, each user has their own ID and this is called 'brukerID'
The table everything is in is called 'brukere' and the column I'm supposed to update is the one called 'brukerBakgrunn'

When I just run the javascript snippet, I get this message box in return where it says:

> Background changed to: 
>   **Warning**:  session_start() [function.session-start]:
>   Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started
>   at
>   /var/www/clients/client2/web8/web/save_to_db.php:1)
>   in
>   **/var/www/clients/client2/web8/web/access.php**
>   on line **3**

This is dbconnect.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("*****","******","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }  

mysql_select_db("****", $con);
require("access.php");
?>
```

And this is access.php:

```
<?php
// Don't mess with ;)
session_start();

if($_REQUEST['inside']) session_destroy();

session_register("inside");
session_register("navn");
if($_SESSION['inside'] == ""){
    if($_POST['brukernavn'] and $_POST['passord']){
    $query = "select * from brukere where brukerNavn='" . $_POST['brukernavn'] . "' and brukerPassord = md5('" . $_POST['passord'] ."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);      
    if(!$result) mysql_error();
    $rows = @mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows > 0){
    $_SESSION['inside'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['navn'] = mysql_result($result,"navn");
    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result,"id");
    Header("Location: /");
    } else {
    $_SESSION['inside'] = 0;
    $denycontent = 1;
    }
    } else {
    $denycontent = 1;
    }
}

if($denycontent == 1){
include ("head.php");
print('   
<body class="bodylogin">
   content content content      
</body>
');
include ("foot.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = $uploadstring WHERE brukerID=" .$_SESSION['id'] ."";
```

should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = $uploadstring WHERE brukerID=" .$_SESSION['id']);
```

closing parenthesis is missing and the quotes ("") are useless.

Read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in order to make your application safe.

EDIT:

```
<?php
 require("dbconnect.php")
?>

<?php
```

This code sends (the part between ?> and <?php) a newline to the output (it's the same as echo "\n") which is not allowed if you want to write to a session variable consequently.

Comment: +1, I edited to fix your typo and wanted to comment about injection. But you already put the injection thingie in and accidentally reverted my correction ;-)

Comment: Ok, I updated the first post. I get a different message from the ajax method. It's about hos it cannot send session cache limiter, header already sent. 

And the data isn't updated either. And if I remove the 'require("dbconnect.php") from the php file, all I get in return from ajax is nothing. So it looks like it's needed.

Comment: Remove the extra ?> <?php part from your code as I wrote in my editted answer. I hope it will help.

Comment: Ah! Ok, so this removed that error message and gave me another :p
Check my updated first post

Comment: $uploadstring = ($_POST['filename']); - I'm not sure for what reason you did wrap the variable with parenthesis. $uploadstring = $_POST['filename']; should be ok.

Comment: Man, I'm so confused with the syntax.. Thanx, I'll try it! :)
Edit: Didn't change anything actually. I still get the exact same error message. At the same line.

Comment: require("dbconnect.php")  <- you miss the semicolon after the command.

Comment: UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = $uploadstring should be UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = '$uploadstring'. Without apostrophes it is not a valid string for mysql (how would it know what is string and what is part of sql syntax?)

Comment: Ok, now I added both the ';' after require dbconnect.php AND added the single quotes around the variable. And now that 'cannot send session cache limiter' appear again. This is very confusing.

Comment: Show us your dbconnect.php script (without credentials) and maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: ?> <-- don't use these marks at the end of files (remove them from dbconnect.php and access.php in your case) - you may have some accidental output after these marks.

Comment: if($_REQUEST['inside']) session_destroy(); -- the warning message mentioned this line so try to leave it out and see what happens.

Comment: Tried removing the session destroy line and that didn't change anything. I'm gonna try removing the ?> from the files that are included by code. Edit: Line 3 in access.php is really just the "session_start();"

Comment: Try to move the session_start(); before require("dbconnect.php");

Comment: Do you mean to move session_start(); or add another in save_to_db.php?
I can't move session_start() from access.php can I? Cause I need that to access index.php in the first place. Or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

*Big security issue!*

You didn't quote and escape the input to the MySQL query. I could easily hack the end, stack another query, and delete your entire database!

Also, you're missing the ending parenthesis at the end of `mysql_query()`.

Comment: And how will you put your query in his Session variable ID? That might be checked and untainted.

Comment: Why session? uploadstring comes from post data.

Comment: So? Even the `$uploadString` isn't quoted + escaped; I could easily hack that one.

Comment: Never heard of quote and escape the input. Can it easily be fixed?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the input (to allow spaces) then backslash escape any of the quotes so that a hacker can't "get out" of the string and form her own MySQL statement.

Comment: @KennyBones Use PDO or mysqli functions! Imho you should go for PDO and prepared statements, so you don't have that much trouble with SQL injections. Besides, all mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the empty line before session_start():

```
?>

<?php
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything because there is no empty line before session_start();
Edit: Sorry, I get what you mean now :) Fixed that one up.

Answer (score 1):

The original error is due to a missing semicolon on the require line.

As others have said, you need to learn about sql injection and using placeholders.  Get out of the habit of using submitted data without using placeholders or escaping first.

Comment: I don't even have a habit! I'm just fumbling around really, trying to learn all of this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//require_once("dbconnect.php");

$uploadstring = $_REQUEST['filename'];

$db_pswd = 'xxx-xxx-xxx';
$db_user = 'john_doe';
$db_table = 'my_table';

$con = mysql_connect( 'localhost' , $user , $pswd );
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db( $db_table , $con );

mysql_query(" UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = '".$uploadstring."'
WHERE brukerID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I think you need to use a fresh code! yours is compromised! ;-))

Comment: Well, I think what I need is to understand how this all work. I mean, the first part of your code is basically what I do as well, prior to logging on to the site. Then, after I've logged on, is the connection still open? Would I need to deliver connection properties again?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the closing ')' in your mysql_query line !

```
mysql_query("UPDATE brukere SET brukerBakgrunn = $uploadstring WHERE brukerID=" .$_SESSION['id'] );
```

You don't need the ."" at the end of your query too.

Answer (score 0):

```
require("dbconnect.php")
```

should be

```
require("dbconnect.php");
```

Comment: If I do that the same error message appear about the 'Cannot send session cache limiter' is shown again.